# Bitshift operator on unsigned short in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to perform a `Bitwise NOT` on an unsigned int in nodeJS/JavaScript. In my understanding every bitwise operator is done on a signed 32bit integer which makes it confusing for me when I want to do it on an unsigned 16bit integer (short). This is what I want to do:

```
c#
ushort value = 41003;
value = (ushort)~value;
//Value is now 24532 which is correct

nodeJS
var value = 41003;
value = ~value;
//value is now -41004 which is NOT correct
```

How do I convert the last value to an unsigned 16bit int in nodeJS/JavaScript?

Comment: Well, node doesn't know you want the value to be an `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do a bitwise AND to get the same result:

```
value = ~value & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: This seems to be the result I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a the maximum value of a 16 bit number and perform a [bitwise XOR `^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)).

```js
function not16Bit(v) {
    return ((1 << 16) - 1) ^  v;
}
 
console.log(not16Bit(41003)); // 24532
console.log(not16Bit(24532)); // 41003
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use the Uint16Array

```
(new Uint16Array([~41003]))[0] //24532
```